# Confusion About C++ 20 Modules

Tags: c++, module, declaration, c++20, definition

In a module, do you have to both create declarations in a .ixx file and definitions in a .cpp file, or do you just put everything in a .ixx file? Is there anything else that I should know about modules?

Answer (score 4):

So basically there are two questions:

---

**Question 1**:

*In a module, do you have to both create declarations in a .ixx file and definitions in a .cpp file, or do you just put everything in a .ixx file?*

---

You can create a module with a single interface file `.ixx` that exports names and includes implementations of all functions and types. Meaning this `.ixx` interface can contain both the function definition and the declaration. You can also put the implementations in one or more separate implementation files, similar to how `.h` and `.cpp` files are used. `

---

**Question 2**:

*Is there anything else that I should know about modules?*

---

- This official cppreference page on [Modules (since C++20)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/modules) explains it very clearly about it.
- And if you are using one of the most common IDEs like Visual Studio then
  this [Overview of modules in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170) will further clarify your concepts.

Answer (score 3):

Modules as a language feature has no concept of an "ixx file". MSVC as a build system decided that it wanted to use a specific extension that by default designates that a file is a module interface unit (partition or primary). But that is not necessitated by either the standard or even MSVC (you can specify individually to the build system that a particular file is an interface unit; the build system simply needs to know about all of the interface units beforehand).

The requirements for declarations and definitions are pretty simple. If a declaration appears within the purview of a module `M` (ie: not part of the global or private fragment of any module unit for the module `M`), *all* declarations of it must appear in the purview of the module `M`. Note that a definition is also a declaration.

The other rule is just a modification of the long-standing rule about inline definitions needing to be visible by the code that uses them. To do this, if you export an inline declaration (and template functions&variables are implicitly inline) from a module interface unit, the definition must also be in one of that module's interface units. And it can't be in a private module fragment.

Other than that, everything is more or less normal C++.