# Why can't I import a module in C++?

Tags: c++, module

I have two .cpp files in my Visual Studio project, main.cpp and another .cpp. In the other .cpp I do:

```
export module myfunctionsmodule;
```

And in main.cpp I do:

```
import myfunctionsmodule;
```

I get the error:

> Could not find module file for module "myfunctionsmodule"

I have enable /std:c++latest and I am using Version 17.2.3

Comment: Do you need to use modules?  Modules make a project more complex.

Comment: Can you rename the other source file to `*.ixx`? Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/modules-cpp?view=msvc-170 _"The `.ixx` extension is required for module interface files in Visual Studio."_

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I've been looking into using modules for a long time now, and each time I've tried to get them working, probably about 4 times now I've run into problems. They're supposed to be superior to headers and improve compilation times and Microsoft recommends using them for all new projects. I don't know why it's this hard.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Confusion About C++ 20 Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71595538/confusion-about-c-20-modules)

Comment: @jabaa I created a file named myfile.ixx and included it in the Visual Studio project. It didn't do anything, still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions for the basic example in my link? Can you provide a [mcve]? There are multiple different possible reasons for this.

Answer (score 3):

Module interface units in Visual Studio should use the `.ixx` file extension.

The file containing the module declaration:

```cpp
export module myfunctionsmodule;
```

should have a file name that ends with `.ixx`.

You can use other extensions, such as `.cpp`, but if you do, you must supply the `/interface` compiler option when you compile from the command line. See the article [/interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/interface?view=msvc-170) at Microsoft Learn.

In the IDE, you can set this option in the Property Pages for the individual file.

1. Right-click the file in Solution Explorer, and choose "Properties". This opens the Properties Pages dialog box.
2. Under "Configuration Properties > C/C++ > All Options", type "Compile As" in the search box which is named "Look for options or switches".
3. Select "Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface)".

You DO NOT have to do these things if the file uses the extension `.ixx`.

Note that module implementation files in Visual Studio do not use the `.ixx` extension. They use `.cpp`. Those are files where the module declaration does not use the keyword `export`.

- `export module my_module;` declares a module interface unit (.ixx)
- `module my_module;` declares a module implementation unit (.cpp)

Comment: It compiles, but I defined a function in the file in which I did export at the top, and another cpp doesn't recognise it, I can't call it.

Comment: Trust me on the `.ixx` thing. Regarding the function, did you add the keyword `export` in front of its declaration?

Comment: So it has to be on the function. OK, yeah it works. I hope this can replace all headers. I hate declaring and then defining stuff, doing things twice I don't like. This would cut the number of files in half. You could technically have no .cpps

Comment: @Zebrafish - You can also do `export {   }` and it will export everything inside the braces. Like most things in C++, there has to be 5 ways to do something. :-)

Comment: **.ixx** is a none-standard extension. It is just a confusing addition that hinders usage of modules.

Comment: My experience is the opposite. When you split a module into an _interface unit_ and an _implementation unit_, it is useful to have file names that differ only in their extensions, e.g., `A.ixx` and `A.cpp`.

Comment: You are right, of course, that the standard does not specify what the extensions must be. Right now there is no consensus, and the situation is more than a little messy. Consider [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html#file-name-requirement), where: "The file name of an importable module unit should end with .cppm (or .ccm, .cxxm, .c++m). The file name of a module implementation unit should end with .cpp (or .cc, .cxx, .c++)."